# SSIS connection via JDBC Driver to Destination

Tags: jdbc, ssis

I am trying to move data from a MS SQL Server Database to a Destination Database via JDBC.  Is there a way to configure JDBC for SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the database was shipped with an ODBC drive too.  Wasn't aware of this.